# How to add a CSS snippet that renders in TinyMCE

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE on an internal form I have to create email newsletters. How can I copy/paste HTML/CSS (like say a generated CSS button) and paste it in TinyMCE so it gets displayed rather than showing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom dialog. How you do that depends on what version of tinymce you using.